# How can I add some sound to my Java JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jpanel, javasound

I am making a Java game in JFrame. The game is almost completed but I want to add some sound to it. Like when the game will start, the sound should also start. I have checked the Internet but the codes are either not working or are very long. Can anyone help me provide some easy codes that will work in JFrame?

Comment: *I have checked the Internet but the codes are either not working or are very long.* - post your code that you tested so we don't spend time making the same suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic example for playing a .wav file:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

class SoundTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //URL file = new URL("file:./flyby1.wav");
        //URL file = new URL("file:c:/users/netro/java/flyby1.wav");
        URL file = new URL("https://www.wavsource.com/snds_2020-10-01_3728627494378403/sfx/air_raid.wav");

        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);

        JButton button = new JButton("Play Clip");
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();
            }
        });

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but when I'm trying to run the program it is showing this message - javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException could not get audio input stream from input URL(in javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem. (I'm using a  .wav file)

Comment: I tested the code exactly as is with the .wav file in the same directory as the class file. It works whether I specify an absolute path or relative path. I don't know how to make the code any simpler. Make sure your .wav file is playable in  the music player on your computer.

Comment: Might be good to explore whether the format of the wav is supported. Some newer formats (24-bit or 32 bit encoding instead of 16-bit, 48000 or 96000 fps instead of 44100 fps) could be throwing this exception.