# Runtime error showing in running .wav audio

Tags: java, swing, audio, jpanel, javasound

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

class SoundTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL file = new URL("file:C:/Users/a/Documents/My/baby.wav");

        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);

        JButton button = new JButton("Play Clip");
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();
            }
        });

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
    }
}
```

I'm trying this code but when I am trying to run it is showing error -

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException:
    could not get audio input stream from input URL (in javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem)
```

Please anyone solve my problem

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct? file:C:/Users/a/Documents/My/baby.wav, the directory naming looks precarious to say the least.

Comment: Use [getAudioInputStream(File)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.io.File)) instead: `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\a\\Documents\\My\\baby.wav");`  That probably won’t make it work, but you should get an exception that tells you why the file can’t be accessed.  (Do you really have a directory named `My` under Documents?  Did you mean `My Music` or something similar?)

Comment: The path is correct it's a folder under Documents.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Change `URL file = new URL("file:C:/Users/a/Documents/My/baby.wav");` to `File file = new File("C:/Users/a/Documents/My/baby.wav"); System.out.println(file.exists()); AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);`. Report all the output, including the ***entire*** stack trace.

Comment: As was stated in your previous question where you got the original code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509691/how-can-i-add-some-sound-to-my-java-jframe, it works for me whether us use an absolute or relative file path. The easiest way to test is to place the file in the same directory as the class file, so you don't worry about making a mistake with the full path.  Did you verify that the file plays in the music app on your computer? How is "a" a valid user. As far as I know on window the user is  5 characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried your code and the file.exists() is returning true but I'm getting the same exception and yes the .wav file is working in my computer and I have tried using other .wav files also but it's showing the same exception.

Comment: 1) Try using a file from the internet: `URL file = new URL("https://www.wavsource.com/snds_2020-10-01_3728627494378403/sfx/air_raid.wav");` 2) Did you search the forum/web for other suggestions.

Comment: *"I'm getting the same exception"* Where is the full stack trace? Please [edit] the question and post that.

Comment: @ArpitMishra and what happened when you tried with a URL from the web? You keep asking for suggestions but you don't follow up when people help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems most likely that one (or both!) of two things could be happening. One is that the addressing of the file is not working. The other is that the file is a format that Java does not support.

I'd put a request for info in the comments but things are getting quite cluttered there!

Can you tell us the format of the wav file? Try checking it's properties. For sure, Java will support 16-bit, 44100 fps, mono or stereo, little endian, which is the most common format. You can check properties using Audacity if the properties from your OS are incomplete. There are a lot more files these days that are 24-bit or 32-bit, or 48000fps or even 92000fps, and Java doesn't support them yet, afaik.

A "safe" test sound would be [this thunder clap](https://freesound.org/people/Erdie/sounds/24003/) at Freesound.org. You can see on the specs on the right side of the page it's 16-bit, 44100 fps stereo. I would download it and add it to your program rather than trying to play it from its web location.

To help test if the addressing is a problem, I would put the sound in the same folder as your SoundTest.java file. Then, use the following line to get the file's URL.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("soundfilename.wav");
```

This will search in the project folder for the resource. There are other addressing modes for different purposes, but this should help with getting the basic code working. Having your program read directly from a disc location, if truly needed, can be worked out after verifying that you have a working sound file.

Comment: Thanks for your help I checked and the .wav file was of 9 kb with 45 kbps of speed. I used another wav file of 2 kb with 352 kbps of speed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The string for the URL you're inputting is incorrect, try this instead:

```
C:\\Users\\a\\Documents\\My\\baby.wav
```

I also recommend reading files form a resources folder instead of from anywhere on your system, [this](https://java2blog.com/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-java/) blog post does a decent job explaining resources.

If you would like an easier way to access different files, I see that you're using the Swing library so consider using the [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) component.

Edit: Changed URL path

Comment: Not correct.  The `//` is part of the [authority](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2), which is not required in a `file:` URL.

Comment: Closer to being correct, but a file path is not a valid URL and cannot be passed to the URL constructor.