# How do I deal with a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for play audio?

Tags: java, audio, illegalargumentexception

I keep getting an exception saying IllegalArgrumentException, it says audio data < 0 and that there is something wrong on line 17. But I see nothing wrong. I want to be able to play audio.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class sound {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException{
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        File file = new File("[ONTIVA.COM] YEAY Sound Effect-HQ.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
        
        String response = scanner.next();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) We don't know what line 17 is, but I would guess you specified an invalid file. 2) I don't know what the point of the Scanner is to play audio. 3) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509714/131872 for a working example which will play a file from the internet (and also show how to load a file from your computer).

Comment: the scanner is meant to avoid the program from terminating before it even plays audio. line 17 is clip.open(audioStream); , and i highly doubt its an invalid file.

Comment: This is such a common problem! I think the suggestions I posted just three days ago at this thread are worth testing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536221/runtime-error-showing-in-running-wav-audio/64547455#64547455