# Play sound in GUI program

Tags: java, swing, javasound

I have been experimenting with Java Swing using a GUI and have hit a wall.  I am trying to play a sound using Java Sound.  Ultimately, I want to push a button and the sound plays.  I have tried a lot of combinations but none seem to work.  Here is the latest code I tried and I code and it reports:

```
Error: could not find or load main class.
```

I am not seeing why:

```
package net.codejava.sound;
 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
 
/**
 * This is an example program that demonstrates how to play back an audio file
 * using the SourceDataLine in Java Sound API.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class AudioPlayerExample2 {
 
    // size of the byte buffer used to read/write the audio stream
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
     
    /**
     * Play a given audio file.
     * @param audioFilePath Path of the audio file.
     */
    void play(String audioFilePath) {
        File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
 
            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
 
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
 
            SourceDataLine audioLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
 
            audioLine.open(format);
 
            audioLine.start();
             
            System.out.println("Playback started.");
             
            byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;
 
            while ((bytesRead = audioStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
                audioLine.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
             
            audioLine.drain();
            audioLine.close();
            audioStream.close();
             
            System.out.println("Playback completed.");
             
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String audioFilePath = "https://codehs.com/uploads/1981fc4b1d2e4123e9cbe7ab8cc1962a";
        AudioPlayerExample2 player = new AudioPlayerExample2();
        player.play(audioFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a File class to read an URL? Shouldn't  you use the URL?

```java
URL url = new URL("https://codehs.com/uploads/1981fc4b1d2e4123e9cbe7ab8cc1962a");
```

Comment: I corrected the use of `File` in favour for `URL` and your URL causes a `mark/reset not supported` exception.  It's unlikely that the source URL points to a "file" and instead points to some kind of imbedded player, but I'm guessing

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"points to some kind of imbedded player"* [Yup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxu89.png). But OP: For the moment I'd focus on fixing `could not find or load main class`. Nothing else could work until that is fixed. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Sound is extremely complex for a Java beginner.  First, create a working GUI.  Second, add the sound.  Third, only MIDI and WAV files are playable through Java sound.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: Finally, after you've mastered using Java, you can consider studying the [Sound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) tutorial.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *"only MIDI and WAV files are playable through Java sound"* Incorrect. Java Sound supports formats via a Service Provider Interface. There is no SPI for MIDI in the standard JRE, but one can be supplied from the JMF (if you can find it). WAV and AU (at least, from memory) *are* supplied with the JRE. An app can use `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` for a list of supported types. That is handy for apps that offer a file chooser to load sounds.

Comment: *I am trying to play a sound using Java Sound* If you are trying to play a .wav file then check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509691/how-can-i-add-some-sound-to-my-java-jframe/64509714#64509714

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple small changes to the tutorial code example you posted, and the program worked perfectly well.

Here are my changes:

(1) Replaced "File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);" with the following:

```
URL audioFile = null;
try {
    audioFile = new URL(audioFilePath);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(2) Added the following line to the module-info file (required if you are using Java 9 or higher):

```
requires java.desktop;
```

My package setting is slightly different, but I assume you know how to properly set up packages. Your class is in the file folder specified by the package statement, yes?

The error being cited: "could not find or load main class" indicates that something is going wrong with how the code is being invoked rather than a problem with the audio part of the code. What version of Java are you using? What IDE? What is the command you are issuing to execute the program? FWIW, my setup that successfully executed this code has an up-to-date Eclipse IDE running Java 11.

Nam Ha Minh's tutorials at codejava.net usually are quite good. I think he is one of the more reliable tutorial writers out there.

Comment: Where does the module-info file go?

requires java.desktop;

I have never seen this.

Comment: Like this?:

public class AudioPlayerExample2  {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
     
    void play(String audioFilePath) {
       
        URL audioFile = null;
try {
    audioFile = new URL(audioFilePath);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String audioFilePath = ("https://codehs.com/uploads/1981fc4b1d2e4123e9cbe7ab8cc1962a");
        AudioPlayerExample2 player = new AudioPlayerExample2();
        player.play(audioFilePath);
    }
}

Comment: (1) Very difficult to read what you have posted in the message without formatting. Can you put this in your question, instead? (2) Use of modules has been part of Java since Java 9. I'm surprised you haven't come across it. It IS possible to run a project without using the module-info file, but it's been so long since I've done so, I didn't think to set up the project that way. (3) So--are you able to run a "Hello world" program? Maybe the thing to do is create that and progressively add you audio code, as a way to avoid the "could not find or load main class" error.

Comment: In this case it's important to let us know what your setup is. IDE? Java version? We are trying to get a program to run, first and foremost. The audio aspect is irrelevant if you are getting "could not find..." error. The program isn't getting far enough along to even be aware of that code (beyond it having successfully compiled).