# Sound effects to Radio Buttons in Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javasound

How do you add sounds effects  to radio Buttons in Java GUI? For example the click sounds when clicking the radio Buttons. Please tell me and explain how.

I didn't try or copied all of those examples and explanations in YouTube years ago are cause they're somewhat Vague and not really exaggerated I just really want to know how. I just wanna know what are the basics. Please do Share. Thank you.

Comment: Which Java GUI? There are several - SWT, JavaFX, Swing...

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509714/131872 for an example that will replay the sound every time a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since I did this.
I would say in your action handler that is where you want to get your sound and then play it.
So somthing like this:

```
  JButton b1 = new JButton("Cool button"); // Make button

  // Create action listener -  play the sound when the button is pressed
  ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
     File localSoundFile = new File("path_to_sound");
     AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(localSoundFile);   
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();   
     // Other action handler stuff
  }
  b1.addActionListener(listener); // Attatch listener to the button
```

Change the code to work with whatever gui framwork you are using, but the overall design should be something similar